# Como Alternar Input Select de acordo com Radio Button

Tags: javascript

Como posso fazer com que ao selecionar um Radio Button apareça um Input select referente a ele

```
      Radio x  ---> mostrar Select x
      Radio y  ---> mostrar Select y  

    <input type="radio" name="x" />
    <input type="radio" name="y" />

   <select size="1" name="unid" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Nª de Passageiros</option>
    <option value="01">01</option>
    <option value="02">02</option>
    <option value="02">03</option>
    <option value="04">04</option>
    </select>


    <select size="1" name="unid" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Veiculos</option>
    <option value="Sedan">Sedan</option>
    <option value="Van">Van</option>
    <option value="Micro-Onibus">Micro</option>
    <option value="Onibus">Onibus</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Javascript na hora outro errado a tag....

Comment: Qual é o "Select x" e qual é o "Select y"? seu HTML não mostra, dê uma melhorada nele ou explique mais detalhadamente.

Comment: pode ser o primeiro select  x e os segundo y

Comment: Ok mas eu também não sei dizer o que você quer dizer com "apareça um Input select referente a ele", aparecer como? no seu html os dois "aparecem", não tem nenhum escondido com algo como um css "display: none", da uma editada que a pergunta está muito ruim.

Comment: E assim.   um select esta a mostra. e outro oculto,  ao clicar no radio x mostrar o select x e oculta o select y e vice versa.....

Answer (score 2):

Se entendi sua pergunta, você precisará inicializar os `selects` ocultos, como foi dito nos comentários. Após selecionar um `radio` você mostra o `select` escolhido.

No exemplo abaixou eu criei a função `mostraSelect()` que verificar se o radio referente a passageiros está marcado. Se sim ele mostra e oculta o referente ao veículos, e vice-versa.

```css
#ddlPassgeiros{
  display:none;
}
#ddlVeiculos{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
  <script>
  
function mostraSelect() {
    if (document.getElementById('rbPassageiro').checked) {
        document.getElementById('ddlPassgeiros').style.display = 'block';
         document.getElementById('ddlVeiculos').style.display = 'none';
    }
    else{
         document.getElementById('ddlPassgeiros').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('ddlVeiculos').style.display = 'block';
    }
}</script>
  <input type="radio" name="x" onclick="javascript:mostraSelect();" id="rbPassageiro"/>Passageiros
   <input type="radio" name="x" onclick="javascript:mostraSelect();"id="rbVeiculo"/>Veiculos
<br/>
   <select size="1" name="unid" class="form-control" id="ddlPassgeiros">
    <option value="">Nª de Passageiros</option>
    <option value="01">01</option>
    <option value="02">02</option>
    <option value="02">03</option>
    <option value="04">04</option>
    </select>


    <select size="1" name="unid" class="form-control" id="ddlVeiculos">
    <option value="">Veiculos</option>
    <option value="Sedan">Sedan</option>
    <option value="Van">Van</option>
    <option value="Micro-Onibus">Micro</option>
    <option value="Onibus">Onibus</option>
    </select>
```